# How to disable title placeholder (Previous/next month dates )in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using FScalendar for previous & next month calendar. How to remove the previous/next month dates from the current calendar?

Comment: YOu can only hide the Previous & Next Month dates...

Answer (score 6):

You can only **HIDE** the Next & Previous month dates.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     fsCalendarObject.placeholderType = .none
}
```

Comment: perfect answer :)